# are Java properties files thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, properties, thread-safety

There is a java application say App1 which creates a new log file for each run, the name of log file is dynamically set in run-time by configuring the log4j.properties file.

The jar of this java application(App1) is used by another application App2 which uses multithreading. Will each thread in App2 will have its own instance of log4j.properties file too, will it be thread safe to change log4j.properties in run-time?

sorry I could not come up with better title for my question, please edit if you think of somethink better

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you are asking, but when working with multiple applications running alongside each other with log4j, bare in mind that log4j's lookup algorithm for properties files is wired into class loaders.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "its own instance", this is unclear.

To me, your App2, should parse your log4j.properties at launch time and then use the same parameters for all its thread, so it's safe to change log4j.properties during run time.

If you want to be able to change log4j.properties at run time and see the change at run time, App2 should re-parse the file each time it is used,i.e. each time you launch a thread to call App1. Here, each threads would have its own version of log4j.properties.

Does that make it thread-unsafe ? I don't think so, as this is the intended behavior and there's no risk that a thread will have a "wrong" copy of log4j.properties since it is when you save the log4j.properties file to the disk that the next time you launch a (App2) thread, it will get this new version. But if you save the file "at the same time" that a thread is launching, the thread may get the older version as the file may have not been written to the disk yet.

Answer (score 0):

log4j.properties is typically only read once during initialization of Log4j. Unless you reset the configuration and make Log4j re-read the file, any changes after launch will be ignored.

If you want to be absolutely certain, share your Log4j initialization code / configuration here for us to check.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not thread safe. Log4J is does not act like mutex so, if it is being accessed in another app (App2) which is creating objects of (App1) in multiple threads. you cannot have thread safety here.

Answer (score 0):

For your APP2 load log4j of APP1 just once in the starting of APP2 and let each  thread of App2 access that same copy in synchronized order otherwise it will not be thread safe.